# Error when running net/http in ruby via the terminal

Tags: ruby, http, terminal

Running a Net::HTTP post request in ruby. I am using the terminal in Ubuntu and receive this error message:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1307:in `send_entity'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1096:in `post'
from (irb):356
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Running the following code:

```
uri = @@url
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri)
response = http.post('/', @@str)
puts response
```

Comment: can you give the value `@@url` and `@@str` ?

Answer (score 0):

"Name or service not known" is a socket level error that is thrown when you cannot resolve a given domain name or are specifying an IP address that cannot be connected to.  No other information will be available without posting the URL and string you are trying to post.

Comment: I am trying to connect to the ebay API sandbox... The URI I use is: https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=AddItem&siteid=0version=733&routing=new

I followed the instructions on the ebay developers site.. But still getting this error.

Comment: That URL you link has `https` in it, meaning that you need to use SSL.  You didn't provide the string so I can't try it, but make sure you're using `require 'net/https'` and not just `require 'net/http'`.